# Migrate Sitecore security(user/domain/roles/groups) between Sitecore instances?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore8

I need to migrate Sitecore 6 user/domain/roles/groups to Sitecore 8.1 .

Can I serialize complete **security**(user/domain/roles/groups) entities, Is there any approach is there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can serialize them and deserialize in the new environment.

Remember that all the passwords will be reset to `b`.

Below there is a screen from Role Manager. There are 2 buttons:

- serialize all roles
- revert all roles

Use first of the to serialize all roles on your Sitecore 6 solution. You will find new directory in your `Data\serialization` folder called `security`.

[image]

Copy the folder to your Sitecore 8 solution. Serialize Sitecore 8 roles, and then click `Revert All Roles` on Sitecore 8 solution. You need to serialize Sitecore 8 roles first, cause if you click `Revert` without serializing them first, all the roles which were not in Sitecore 6 but were in Sitecore 8 will be removed.

Repeat those steps for domains and users.

Chapter 2.2.3 of the [Sitecore Serialization Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/serialization_guide_sc60-64-a4.pdf) covers the topic.

And here is a guide on [Transferring user passwords between Sitecore instances](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/242631)

Comment: Hi marek can you please brief the approach. I need how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the brief @Marek. Will it covers access rights?

Comment: If you mean access right to items, the answer is *no*. They are stored on items directly.

Comment: I meant in access viwer user x has (read,write,rename,delete,admin)access for content ,layout, sub layout But user admin have (read,write,rename,delete,admin) all access to content,layout,masters,system...etc. This type of access information for users will preserve when I use your approach.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. The answer is **NO**. This information is stored within items in the Sitecore tree. Migration of users/roles/domains only will not migrate access rights, cause they are stored in another place. However, if you have **exactly** the same item in Sitecore 6 and Sitecore 8, including all their fields, migrated users and roles will have same access rights as they had in Sitecore 6.

Answer (score 3):

It's also possible to use the Sitecore Package Designer to transfer both roles and users:

[image: SItecore Package Designer]

Bear in mind that any users transferred like this would have their password reset to a random value due to the fact that Sitecore stores passwords in a hashed format in the database.

To migrate domains, by default Sitecore will add these to `/App_Config/Security/Domains.config` so either add this file into your Visual Studio project or copy it across instances.